# How to achieve fault tolerance in cloud?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, load-balancing, fault-tolerance

I am working on a project which aims at achieving fault tolerant cloud through elastic IP addressing and load balancing. Initially, I opted for Windows Azure but it provides automatic fault handling through its portal and user cannot control the access to the instances on cloud. I have read about amazon EC2 but I'm not sure whether it gives me freedom to handle the instances programmatically and not manually through Amazon's portal. I'm new in this domain. So I need help on how do I proceed with my project. My algorithm involves direct access to the instances on which my web application runs or my data is stored. Thank you.

Comment: The project is of Final Year Engineering Degree level.

Comment: It is just that, an entire project. You need to break it down into specifics, it's far too broad in scope currently to answer in last than 10 hours.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.

I have my network set up in the cloud and I do everything from starting a new server, installing software, and monitoring without ever using the GUI from Amazon. Their API tools do everything that their GUI can do and more.

Using a combination of their Elastic Load Balancing, Auto Scaling Groups and CloudWatch you can create a very fault tolerant environment with very little effort.

I don't understand why you would need Elastic IP's though. By nature they're not fault tolerant, if the machine that the ip is assigned to crashed you need to manually assign the ip to another machine. This process doesn't take long but its defiantly not highly available or fault tolerant.

Amazons Elastic Load Balancer is defiantly is a very fault tolerant product, load balanced instances can be spread across regions, which means you can have up to 5-6 instances each behind a separate set of hardware. If somehow amazon experiences an outage in one of the regions you still have your application online.

The Elastic Load Balancer will also monitor a port on each of the instances to check the health of the application running on the instance, in addition to health checks on the application amazon also does a health check of the hardware and will replace your instance on failure.